# Is there an elegant way to pass npm run options to grunt options

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a package.json which looks like below,

```json
{
  "scripts": {
   "start": "node app.js",
   "test": "./node_modules/.bin/grunt test"
  }
}
```

I would like to invoke the test script via `npm run test` with parameters like:

```
npm run test --host=<value1> --testType=<value2>
```

Is there a way to read these parameters as grunt options via `grunt.option` inside the grunt file?

If I pass these parameters like:

```
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/grunt test --host=<value1> --testType=<value2>"
```

but based on the `testType` the nature of the test run would be different - so it would be nice if those values can be read from `npm run`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) is what you're after, but:

> As of `npm@2.0.0`, you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option `--` is used by getopt to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the `--` directly to your script